# Flutter generating invalid sourcemaps

Tags: flutter, dart, sentry

I am generating source maps with this command :

```
flutter build web --release --source-maps
```

When I open the app in browser every flutter file just contains the index.html content.
Also tried to upload the source map on sentry and it says invalid mapping (Invalid location in sourcemap)
So I think source map must be broken.

Comment: It may be linked to this github issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/87734